# Is "!ERROR" return code convention normal in C?

Tags: c

I'm looking through some legacy C source code and the author has defined some error code enums which include ERROR (`-1`) and SUCCESS (`0`). Throughout the code however, they have used the convention `!ERROR` as a return code from a function.

This should presumably relate to SUCCESS (`0`).

Has anyone seen this before? Does it make sense to you?

Comment: There are many different ways to handle errors. As long as you are consistent in applying one technique you should be fine.

Comment: not error means success. So why do think it is wrong

Answer (score 4):

Using zero to mean success and a negative value, often `-1`, to mean failure is a very common convention.  The Unix system calls use this extensively (sometimes with a non-negative number meaning success when, for example, a file descriptor is returned).

There are definitely other conventions too — [OpenSSL](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Libcrypto_API#Error_Handling) uses a different one, for example: `0` means failure and `1` means success.  This has the advantage that you can write:

```
if (OpenSSL_API_Function(arg1, arg2, &arg3))
{
    …continue on success;
}
```

Using `!ERROR` rather than `0` or `SUCCESS` or `OK` is less usual.  It certainly isn't wrong as the logical negation of any non-zero value is zero.  The authors presumably consider '`!ERROR`' as similar to writing 'no error' and think it is clearer than `SUCCESS` or `OK`.  Generally, avoid negations just for the fun of it; it can lead to convoluted thinking.